# How to resolve "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages" error in Debian 9?

Tags: debian, apt

I am trying to install `software-properties-common` on my Debian 9. But i get the error which states

> The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
>   software-properties-common : Depends: python3-software-properties (=
>   0.96.20.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
>                                 Recommends: packagekit but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held
>   broken packages.

I have tried many solutions like `apt update -f` (as suggested by most of the debian users) but nothing worked for me.

Here is my `source.list` file:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non$

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: you can use an iterative approach until the real problem is found. 1st round: `apt-get -d install software-properties-common python3-software-properties=0.96.20.2-1 packagekit` (you can leave packagekit alone it's only recommended)

Comment: @A.B I had already tried this. I get the same error for `python3-software-properties`

Comment: Maybe this happened after you did something special but didn't write in the question? Did you update (with `apt update` , *not* `apt update -f` which is illegal) before trying ?